# Arduino Serial library cannot find "availableForWrite()" function

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, arduino-ide

I'm trying to get Arduino to send some chars back to my raspberry pi via the serial USB port.

However, when I try to use the function "Serial.availableForWrite()", the compiler failed with:
error: ‘class HardwareSerial’ has no member named ‘availableForWrite’
the rest of the code piece works fine though.

Here is the entire code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  // connect to serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  // write value
  if (Serial.availableForWrite() > 0) {
    Serial.write("0.587");
  }
  Serial.write("Error");
  delay(1000);
}
```

I am pretty sure my Arduino IDE is up to date, and also I don't think I have spelling mistakes. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: This codes compiles for me without any issue. Which board do you use?

Answer (score 0):

i dont have any problems with this code neither when compiling and i can even upload this sketch to my arduino uno this problem might be ocuring due to the usage of an raspbery pei maybe try and use an arduino board

Comment: Yea I found the solution. I installed arduino IDE with `sudo apt install arduino`, which downloads a very old version ( around 1.0.x, the newest is 1.8.x) of the arduino IDE. I simply remove it and download the newest release from the official arudino website.